# How to show total number of comments for each user

Tags: sql

I think this is the solution but I can't verify it yet due to some technical issues
It's a social media database

`SELECT username, COUNT(user.id) AS NumOfComments`

`FROM user, comment`

`WHERE user.id = comment.user_id GROUP BY user.id`

(Might be wrong)

How would you do it? Is my method even correct?

[image: Image here]

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it maybe right,but I prefer use `JOIN` which is more clear

```sql
SELECT 
    username, COUNT(comment.user_id) AS NumOfComments
    FROM user
    LEFT JOIN comment on (user.id = comment.user_id)
    GROUP BY user.id
```